# PHP - Get relative path from one directory to another

Tags: php, directory, path

Lets say I have these two directory paths:

**"/www/website/news/old/"**

**"/www/library/js/"**

I need a PHP function that would output a relative path from one directory to another. In this example it should output something like **"../../../library/js/"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following function would do the job:

```
function getRelativePath($source, $destination) {
    $sourceArray = [];
    preg_match_all('/([^\/]+)/', $source, $sourceArray);
    $destinationArray = [];
    preg_match_all('/([^\/]+)/', $destination, $destinationArray);
    
    $sourceArray = array_reverse($sourceArray[0]);
    $destinationArray = array_reverse($destinationArray[0]);
    
    $relative = [];
    $hasPath = false;
    foreach ($sourceArray as $path) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($destinationArray); $i++ ) {
            $to = $destinationArray[$i];
            if ($path == $to) {
                $hasPath = true;
                for ($j = $i - 1; $j >= 0 ; $j--)
                    $relative[] = $destinationArray[$j];
                break 2;    
            }
        }
        $relative[] = "..";
    }
    return $hasPath ? implode("/",$relative) . "/" : "NO PATH";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function given the source and destination **exist**:

```
function getRelativePath($source, $destination)
{
    $paths =
        array_map(fn ($arg) => explode('/', realpath($arg)), func_get_args());
    return
        str_repeat('../', count(array_diff_assoc(...$paths))) .
        implode('/', array_diff_assoc(...array_reverse($paths)));
}
```

Nothing fancy. No check is implemented on the source being a folder and not a file.

Note: the destination can be a file while the source is supposed to be a directory from where the relative path is calculated.